# Android Popup Menu + Database and view changing question

Tags: java, android, popupmenu

I'm trying to create a popup menu when a button is pressed.
The popup menu is to be generated with the values from a column in the database, and when the user clicks on the menu options, it should then call the function to retrieve all of the items that are associated with that value in the database.

Context: It's a simple shopping list, and the button should allow you to bring up ONLY the items at a particular store.

The problem I'm having is with the "onclick" handler. I actually have no idea how to do this. 
This is what I tried to do and it tells me "item is already declared in this scope", but if I remove the "MenuItem" datatype to pass "item" it still says it's already defined.

I have a feeling it's because it's creating a method with its own parameter and not actually passing the menu item to it. 
Does it automatically pass the menu item if I simply give it a different param such as (MenuItem) clickedItem ?

```
public void btnDisplayByStore(View v){
        PopupMenu puStoreSelect = new PopupMenu(home_screen.this, findViewById(R.id.btnSearchByStore));
        DatabaseManager DBM = new DatabaseManager(this);
        ArrayList<String> alStores = DBM.getStores();

        for(int i = 0; i < alStores.size(); i++) {
            MenuItem item = puStoreSelect.getMenu().add(alStores.get(i));
            puStoreSelect.setOnMenuItemClickListener((MenuItem item) -> {
                populateItemListByStore(item.getTitle().toString());
                return true;
            });
        }
        puStoreSelect.getMenuInflater().inflate(alStores.size(), puStoreSelect.getMenu());
    }
```

Comment: did you try move setOnMenuItemClickListener outside loop.

Comment: Does it automatically pass the menu item if I simply give it a different param such as (MenuItem) clickedItem ? sure it depend on item available in menu, and pass correct item clicked

Comment: It was originally outside of the loop.(Didn't compile then either.) I moved it inside the loop because I realized it should be creating a listener for each item within the menu. Also, I tried removing the menuitem definition and simplying  having "puStoreSelect.geTMenu().add(alStores.get(i)); without the variable. When I do that, it tells me that it can't resolve the getTitle() method, despite it being a method belonging to the item class.